# ispin help (unreachable states in LTL formula)

Tags: java, model-checking, spin, formal-methods

I have modeled a system in ispin and when trying to verify the system using LTL formulas I found unreachable error like

```
unreached in claim l0
    _spin_nvr.tmp:8, state 9, "(!((getReciept&&getCard)))"
    _spin_nvr.tmp:10, state 11, "-end-"
    (2 of 11 states)
```

my ltl formula was

```
ltl0{[]((cardeject && getCash)  ->   <>(getReciept && getCard))}
```

Comment: You can use formatting to make the examples readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a warning, not an error. This is because the part `(cashDispensed && !continueTransaction)` might never become true. So, the formula is trivially true.

You can disable the warning by unchecking the checkbox "*report unreachable code*" in iSpin.